# Date range loop into bbdd

Tags: php, sql

I want to make different tables from 2 variables: start date and end date.

Example: input start= 05/07/2022 input end= 07/07/2022

so, when I submit the form I want this result:

ddbb: id:01 05/07/2022 id:02 06/07/2022 id:03 07/07/2022

I tried this but I got the dates displace, like this:

id:01 06/07/2022 id:02 07/07/2022 id:03 08/07/2022

This is the code:

```
<?php

require('db.php');

if (isset($_REQUEST['DIACOMIENZO'])){

$DIACOMIENZO = $_REQUEST['DIACOMIENZO'];
$DIAFIN = $_REQUEST['DIAFIN'];

while (strtotime($DIACOMIENZO) <= strtotime($DIAFIN)) {
    
    
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO DIASHORARIOS (DIA) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $DIACOMIENZO);
    
    
    $DIACOMIENZO = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 days", strtotime($DIACOMIENZO)));
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
    
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you increased the date by 1 day even *before* you inserted it into the database. If you want the first value to be the start date, insert it, and then increment it afterwards.

For example:

```
while (strtotime($DIACOMIENZO) <= strtotime($DIAFIN))
{
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO DIASHORARIOS (DIA) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $DIACOMIENZO);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();    
    
    $DIACOMIENZO = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 days", strtotime($DIACOMIENZO)));
}
```